# Python metaclass and the object base class

Tags: python, metaclass

After reading the excellent [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949), I tried crafting a module level metaclass:

```
def metaclass(future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attrs):
    print "module.__metaclass__"
    future_class_attrs["bar"]="bar"
    return type(future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attrs)

__metaclass__=metaclass


class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Foo.__init__'

f=Foo()
```

This doesn't work (i.e. "module.**metaclass**" doesn't get printed) unless I remove the `object` base class of Foo.  How come?

NOTE: I am using Python 2.6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheriting from *object* automatically brings the *type* metaclass along with it.  This overrides your module level *__metaclass__* specification.

If the metaclass is specified at the class level, then *object* won't override it:

```
def metaclass(future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attrs):
    print "module.__metaclass__"
    future_class_attrs["bar"]="bar"
    return type(future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attrs)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = metaclass

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Foo.__init__'

f=Foo()
```

See [http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=**metaclass**#customizing-class-creation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__metaclass__#customizing-class-creation)

Comment: The specification says no such thing. What it does say is that if there is a baseclass, the metaclass of the baseclass will be used, regardless of whether or not the baseclass specifies a metaclass.

Answer (score 2):

The specification [specifies the order in which Python will look for a metaclass](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__metaclass__#customizing-class-creation):

> The appropriate metaclass is determined by the following precedence
>   rules:
>
> - If `dict['__metaclass__']` exists, it is used.
> - Otherwise, if there is at
>     least one base class, its metaclass is used (this looks for a
>     `__class__` attribute first and if not found, uses its type).
> - Otherwise, if a global variable named `__metaclass__` exists, it is used.
> - Otherwise, the old-style, classic metaclass (`types.ClassType`) is used.

You will see from the above that having a base class *at all* (whatever the base class is, even if it does not ultimately inherit from `object`) pre-empts the module-level `__metaclass__`.