# What is wrong with this simple python metaclass?

Tags: python, metaclass

> Digression Start

I just learnt what metaclasses are in Python. I don't think that the creators of python wanted everyone to use them. I mean name something a metaclass which might not be a class in most cases is enough to divert most people away from this concept!

> Digression end

**On to my question. I wrote this simple metaclass to add a default doc string to all classes that are created in the module. But it is not working:**

```
def metest(cls,name,bases,dict):
    cls.setattr(cls,'__doc__',"""Default Doc""")
    return type(cls,(),{})

__metaclass__=metest

class test(object):
    pass

print test.__doc__

t=test()

print t.__doc__
```

Output:

```
None
None
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made your example work:

```
def metest(name, bases, dict):
    print name, bases, dict
    dict['__doc__'] = """New Doc"""
    cls = type(name+"_meta", bases, dict)
    return cls

class Test(object):
    "Old doc"
    __metaclass__ = metest

print Test
print Test.__doc__

t = Test()

print t.__doc__
```

1. Make the "meta class" used.
2. Correct the signature of the "class creation function". The `cls` will be created by us.
3. Have an "old" and a "new" docstring in order to distinguish.

Comment: It _is_ possible to use a global metaclass, just don't inherit from `object`

Comment: Who should not inherit from object? The metaclass or ALL the classes in the module?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely familiar with the global approach you are doing, setting `__metaclass__` like that. For all I know, its another valid style.

But I will provide an example of what I am familiar with:

```
class MeTest(type):
    def __new__(cls,name,bases,dict):
        dict['__doc__'] = """Default Doc"""
        return type.__new__(cls,name,bases,dict)

class Test(object):
    __metaclass__ = MeTest
```

Answer (score 2):

See this answer: [Python metaclass and the object base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958212/python-metaclass-and-the-object-base-class)

Providing the `object` base class overrides the module-level metaclass and replaces it with `type` (the metaclass of `object`).

In addition, your metaclass is faulty and won't work even if you get it to apply (by setting `__metaclass__` inside the class).  It should only accept three arguments.  You usually see examples that accept four, but that's because the metaclass is usually, guess what, a *class*, so it accepts an extra "self" argument (which by convention is called `cls` for metaclasses).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this is what you want. Inheriting from `object` would make the metaclass `type`, so you can't do that if you want to use a global metaclass

```
def metest(name, bases, dct):
    dct['__doc__'] = """Default Doc"""
    return type(name, bases, dct)

__metaclass__=metest

class test:
    pass

print test.__doc__

t=test()

print t.__doc__
```

Comment: But shouldn't the metaclass necessarily be a type? Because from what I have understood, all the classes in Python are objects of the `type` class. So if i want to alter all the classes then I need to override the `type` which is what `metaclass` does. So then why should I NOT inherit from `type`? Is it because then it inherits from the non-overridden `type` class? I am confused. :S

Comment: @ritratt, `metest` is a function that _returns_ a class that _inherits from type_. The global `__metaclass__=metest` only works for classic classes. Once you inherit from `object` you are setting the metaclass back to `type` unless the class then overrides the metaclass again

Answer (score 1):

Your module-level metaclass is overridden, just as stated above by BrenBarn.
To fix this, try to code it to *return cls* instead of setting it as a class instance.